# Print all timestamps between two timestamps

Tags: java, timestamp

Like the title says, given two dates with times like

```
time1= "2017-01-31 12:00:00" 
time2= "2017-01-31 15:00:00”
```

I want to return all timestamps within an array that are between these two times and dates. For example this is what the array will look like:

```
2017-01-31 01:33:30 random text log message x

2017-01-31 08:34:30 sdfsd log message y

2017-01-31 11:35:30 sdfsdfsdf log message z

2017-01-31 12:30:30 random text log message x

2017-01-31 13:31:30 sdfsd log message y

2017-01-31 14:32:30 sdfsdfsdf log message z

2017-01-31 16:32:35 sdfsdfsdf log message a

2017-01-31 16:33:30 random text log message x

2017-01-31 16:34:30 sdfsd log message y

2017-01-31 16:35:30 sdfsdfsdf log message z

2017-01-31 16:36:35 sdfsdfsdf log message a
```

Output:

```
2017-01-31 12:30:30 random text log message x

2017-01-31 13:31:30 sdfsd log message y

2017-01-31 14:32:30 sdfsdfsdf log message z
```

Would I have to use regex to store the time and date of each separate time/date stamp and then compare them to each timestamp in the array? Or what would be an optimal solution?

Comment: well, you know the date is 20 characters long, so you can get the date string using substring and then parse it with DateFormat to check if it is between the 2 dates

Comment: They have to be between the two times as well

Comment: you parse time1, time2, and the your timestamp into dates, and then check if it is between the two times like this. `timestamp.after(time1) && timestamp .before(time2)`

Comment: Can you possibly make this into a formal answer? But are saying I can make this DateFormat object of the form: "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" and then I can use .before and .after?

Comment: Can we assume that the array is always sorted by date and time?

Comment: Where I once worked we wrote an application that would pick up the log from another application. The log lines had time stamps in the same format as yours. In October, when summer time ended and the clocks were turned backward, for one hour our application rejected every time stamp from the log because the time appeared to go backward. So in the end we had the log file format changed. You may consider ISO 8601 with offset from UTC, offset `Z` (zero) is recommended, so best `2017-01-31T00:33:30Z`, else `2017-01-31T01:33:30+01:00`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, you know the date is 20 characters long, so you can get the date string using substring and then parse it with DateFormat to check if it is between the 2 dates.      you parse time1, time2, and the your timestamp into dates, and then check if it is between the two times like this. `timestamp.after(time1) && timestamp .before(time2)`

```
    String time1= "2017-01-31 12:00:00" 
        String time2= "2017-01-31 15:00:00”

        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        Date minDate = format.parse(time1);
        Date maxDate = format.parse(time2);

        for(String row : somearray){
            String rowDateString = row.substring(0,19);
            Date rowDate = format.parse(rowDateString);
            if(rowDate.after(minDate) && rowDate .before(maxDate){
                //get this row because it is between dates
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 3):

### java.time

```
    DateTimeFormatter logDtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    String[] logMessages = {
            "2017-01-31 01:33:30 random text log message x",
            "2017-01-31 08:34:30 sdfsd log message y",
            "2017-01-31 11:35:30 sdfsdfsdf log message z",
            "2017-01-31 12:30:30 random text log message x",
            "2017-01-31 13:31:30 sdfsd log message y",
            "2017-01-31 14:32:30 sdfsdfsdf log message z",
            "2017-01-31 16:32:35 sdfsdfsdf log message a",
            "2017-01-31 16:33:30 random text log message x",
            "2017-01-31 16:34:30 sdfsd log message y",
            "2017-01-31 16:35:30 sdfsdfsdf log message z",
            "2017-01-31 16:36:35 sdfsdfsdf log message a"
    };

    String time1 = "2017-01-31 12:00:00";
    String time2 = "2017-01-31 15:00:00";

    LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.parse(time1, logDtf);
    LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.parse(time2, logDtf);

    Arrays.stream(logMessages)
            .filter(lm -> {
                TemporalAccessor parsedDateTime = logDtf.parse(lm, new ParsePosition(0));
                LocalDateTime logDateTime = LocalDateTime.from(parsedDateTime);
                return ! logDateTime.isBefore(start)
                        && logDateTime.isBefore(end);
            })
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The output from this code is what you asked for:

> ```
> 2017-01-31 12:30:30 random text log message x
> 2017-01-31 13:31:30 sdfsd log message y
> 2017-01-31 14:32:30 sdfsdfsdf log message z
> ```

I am using java.time, the modern Java date and time API. I always recommend it for any date-time work in Java. I find it so nice to work with.

I am filtering to the *half-open* interval between your times. This means, a log message stamped exactly 2017-01-31 12:00:00 will be included, while a message stamped 2017-01-31 15:00:00 will not. This is usual and recommended use of time intervals. One advantage is if you filter to adjacent (non-overlaping) intervals, each log message is guaranteed to be included exactly once.

If your array is very large and always sorted and performance matters, you can benefit from using binary search for the start and end of the desired interval. Look it up if it’s relevant and you don’t already know what it is.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.

Comment: Wouldn't binary search only be viable if the array is sorted?

Comment: @Jack Yes, indeed. That was why I asked under your question whether it would always be. Your example array looked like it was, so I dared put it into the answer without awaiting your answer. If you aren’t completely sure, you shouldn’t rely on it, of course.